# Ubuntu 18.04 and CUDA

Tags: 18.04, cuda

Trying to install CUDA 91. on Ubuntu 18.04. NVidia only has it for 16 and 17.10. I've tried installing `libcudart9.1`, `nvidia-cuda-dev`, and `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` from the repo.

Since there's nothing in `/usr/local` (which is where it gets put when I do it in CentOS), and there's nothing in `/opt`, I'm assuming that the parts of CUDA I'm used to seeing have not been installed.

Anyone got a clue for what to install on 18.04?

Comment: You might want to see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077061/how-do-i-install-nvidia-and-cuda-drivers-into-ubuntu as the CUDA 10. and the 410 drivers that are non-beta have just been released for Ubuntu 18.04