# How to install latest version of CUDA on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

I tried to install CUDA on Ubuntu but got errors.

I follow official guide for installation. And actually I succeed on my own mac.
But on ubuntu 18.04 machine, when I tried to test those samples, it showed that no CUDA-capable device detected, but actually there is an nvidia GPU, GTX470.
Also, "nvidia-smi" command doesn't work, saying can't find the CUDA driver, but actually, if we run apt-get install cuda driver, it showed that cuda driver is already installed. You may check the error image:

[image: Error message]

Comment: Don't use the Wayland login option, it switches the display to the integrated graphics.  Even running Wayland, the non-graphics CUDA samples should still run.

Comment: I agree with @ubfan1 above and make sure you are logging in using the XOrg option. Your graphics card is listed at using the 396.18 driver.  If you follow the answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1086993/231142 but download CUDA 10 from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=runfilelocal) you should be able to step through and set it up correctly.  I can try to write an answer later if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use the installation guide provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1036265/853882) by eromod. This worked for me on 18.04 on different computers, other than the official version.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

sudo apt update

sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

reboot

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit gcc-6

nvcc --version
```

Comment: You are welcome, please mark the answer as "accepted" then. :) @JadenPan