# How to install cuda 10.0 with nvidia-418 driver on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda, 19.04, tensorflow

I just upgraded my system to Ubuntu 19.04 and realized Cuda 10.0 is not getting installed. tensorflow is still not built for Cuda 10.1 and it would be great if I can downgrade my Nvidia driver from 418 to 410 if possible. I am using Geforce GTX 1060.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer in the following answer:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1077063/864216

For some reason, I had to use `

> sudo aptitude install cuda-10-0

`

Comment: For all those, who read this. It seems aptitude also automatically handles unmatched dependencies and thus it is easier to install cuda-10-0 with aptitude. Aptitutde is probably not installed on your machine. So you get it via `apt-get install aptitude`.

Answer (score 1):

please run this:

```
sudo apt-get install cuda-10-0
```

if you have installed cuda before,

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove cuda-10-0
```

and install again.

After installing, download cudnn from archive: https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive, and unzip it.
After that please do below:

```
sudo cp -P cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda-10.0/include
sudo cp -P cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/
sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/libcudnn*
```