# rtx 2060 driver not initalizing after few reboots on 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, gnome, cuda

I've got this problem with Nvidia driver for a few months now. Here is what I am usually doing:

I stop gdm3 (`sudo service gdm3 stop`), install driver with `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-418.74.run --no-x-check`, then following instructions, then blacklisting noveau using `blacklist-nouveau.conf` file - it contains `blacklist nouveau` and 
`options nouveau modeset=0` then I install cuda, cudnn etc... Everything works properly including `nvidia-smi`, I can run code on gpu (some NN models in tensorflow). After few reboots my driver breaks down. I boot into login screen set in 800x600 resolution without option to change it. `nvidia-smi` reports it cannot connect to driver. Then I reinstall driver and then it works for a while, but after few reboots it breaks down again.

Few times I reinstalled everything completely, including Cuda etc., no change in behavioer, however. Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: I had the same problem using Nvidia Driver version 430.26. I installed the version 430.26 and ignored the warnings,it was working fine but after few days I upgraded the system to newer kernel and the problem was the same with the resolution. I reinstalled Ubuntu and using the Graphic Driver from apt-repository seems to be fine for now.. btw check  this -> Automatic Install using PPA repository to install Nvidia Beta drivers  in https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that! However, I am afraid that Beta drivers will not work properly with Cuda. Do you have any experience with that?

Comment: I dont have experience with that, but based on this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077061/how-do-i-install-nvidia-and-cuda-drivers-into-ubuntu it seems to work using the repository ppa:graphic-drivers/ppa