# Running steam on machine with the nvidia 4.55 driver

Tags: nvidia, steam, 32-bit, opengl

So my NVIDIA driver is latest:

```
$ dpkg --list | grep libnvidia-gl
ii  libnvidia-gl-455:amd64                     455.32.00-0ubuntu1                    amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
```

But steam will not launch. Allegedly, this is because it is missing 32 bit libraries.

When I try to install the 32 bit GL library, I get:

```
$ sudo apt-get install  libnvidia-gl-455:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libnvidia-gl-455:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libnvidia-common-455

E: Package 'libnvidia-gl-455:i386' has no installation candidate
```

And following the prompted solution:

```
$ sudo apt-get install  libnvidia-common-455:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libnvidia-common-455:i386
```

So, how can I get the 32 bit version of libGL for nvidia?

NOTE: I cannot downgrade my nvidia-driver to an earlier version, as CUDA requires latest, and my development uses CUDA.

Comment: You would have to request to NVIDIA themselves for the 32bit drivers to be added.  In the `graphics-drivers` PPA it only goes up to the 450 driver which has the 32bit drivers.  Also, if you install CUDA from the `.run` file, you can unselect the driver that is used that way you can use pretty much whatever driver you want.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1077063/231142 where I cover the .run file installation.

Comment: You can download up to the CUDA 11.1 version from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive

Answer (score -2):

This is a common problem. The best solution I found so far is this post:
[Installing 32-bit libnvidia-gl alongside 64-bit version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295293/installing-32-bit-libnvidia-gl-alongside-64-bit-version)
The main point to install 32 bit manually by using a run file from Nvidia. This way you can have both 64 and 32 bits on your machine.