# Does the NVIDIA CUDA repositories contain more updated drivers than the ones in NVIDIA website, and are those drivers good enough for Proton?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, wine, cuda

I have installed CUDA 11 using the [instructions provided by NVIDIA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=2004&target_type=debnetwork):

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2004.pin
sudo mv cuda-ubuntu2004.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/ /"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

If I run `nvidia-settings`, I have version 460 of the drivers, while the short-lived drivers on [NVIDIA website](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/166883/en-us) lists as the latest driver version 455:

[image]

1. Does those NVIDIA repositories contain more updated drivers than the ones provided on the website?
2. Are my drivers good enough for [Proton](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Proton), which says that:

> Proton requires graphics drivers that are more recent than what is
> typically packaged in most distributions

?

Comment: Honestly, you can bump into issues using the drivers directly from NVIDIA.  I would recommend using the `graphics-drivers` PPA as they are up to using 455.38.  One of the biggest issues is that the driver direct from NVIDIA can actually get removed during kernel updates, where the drivers in the PPA use DKMS to get carried over during each kernel install / update. Plus, the drivers that come from NVIDIA direct that are that new usually are missing i386 drivers that can cause Steam, etc to no longer work.

Comment: @Terrance Thanks for your answer, the problem is that I need CUDA for deeplearning in Tensorflow, and installing CUDA installs those drivers in my system

Comment: If you download the CUDA `.run` file of the installer, you can unselect the video drivers for installation.  The rest of the install will still work just fine.  I have written an answer for 20.04 with the CUDA 11.1, but I know that you can get the newest CUDA from the links I put in there.  https://askubuntu.com/a/1288405/231142