# how should I install cuda, NVIDIA drivers cuDNN?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics, cuda

I've been trying all weekend to install cuDNN, cuda, and the proper drvivers for my NVIDIA GTX 1060. clean installs, various versions, OEM driver, Ubuntu driver. ... I Dont know anymore.
There is software I want to run that depends on cuda, and cuDNN, and it would seem installing the wrong version of either will break my system. Im using either Ubuntu Mate 18.04, or Ubuntu Mate 20.04 (I have 2 systems im trying the same thing on) (OEM has cuDNN package for 18.04, but not 20.04, so now Im trying both).

Im tired of breaking my systems, I have supported hardware, what is the method for installing cuda, cuDNN, and the NVIDIA drivers? should I install the OEM drivers? the OEM says I should use the ubuntu drivers. should I install the drivers first, or nvidia-cuda-toolkit?

I dont know what to do, first last or otherwise.

Comment: There are several answered questions on this site about this, depending upon what you want to do.  I think Kufty had a pretty complete installation inst recently, and I have an older one to just unpack the debs into local directories to allow multiple versions of CUDA simutaneously.  Since your hw is sufficient, go from the desired sw (cudnn, tensorflow,...) cuda requirements -- the stable versions of cudnn... may not allow the latest CUDA.

Comment: I prefer doing the `.run` file installation as then I can use the `graphics-drivers` PPA drivers that carry over when getting kernel updates, etc.  https://askubuntu.com/a/1288405/231142

Comment: @Terrance appoligies, your's was the one I attributed to kufty.

Comment: @ubfan1 Ah, no worries.  =)