# Ubuntu 20.04 breaks periodically cuda 11.0

Tags: 20.04, cuda, gpu-driver

Installed the Ubuntu 20.04 system. GPU driver 450.102.04 and cuda toolkit 11.0. cudnn packages are not installed. The computer works around the clock, processing data on GPU cores. A periodic error occurs when the cuda settings fly off, that is, the operating system and the program stops seeing cuda and reports that this library is not installed. The problem is solved by reinstalling cuda, but the error occurs very often. Does anyone have any thoughts on how to solve the problem of periodic system drivers crashing?

Comment: It is probably breaking the driver because the NVIDIA drivers do not install the `dkms` drivers that will carry over into new kernel updates/upgrades.  Try maybe installing the drivers from the PPA instead.  See https://askubuntu.com/a/1288405/231142  in the answer you can install the 460 drivers if desired.