# CUDA 11.3 installation failure on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, cuda

I have installed Ubuntu desktop 18.04 on HP laptop with nVidia graphics card GM107GLM [Quadro M2000M]:

```
$ sudo lshw -C display
*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: GM107GLM [Quadro M2000M]
vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
version: a2
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
resources: irq:133 memory:e4000000-e4ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:e5080000-e50fffff
*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: HD Graphics 530
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 2
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
version: 06
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
resources: irq:131 memory:e3000000-e3ffffff memory:40000000-4fffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I have installed nvidia-driver-460:

```
$ nvidia-smi 
Sat May 22 16:03:23 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.73.01    Driver Version: 460.73.01    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro M2000M       Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   33C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    716MiB /  4043MiB |      5%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2145      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                551MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2332      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               33MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2939      G   ...AAAAAAAA== --shared-files        6MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3456      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files       12MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9540      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files       49MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9843      G   ...oken=17184766749938794993        8MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9957      G   /opt/zoom/zoom                      5MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     10072      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files       34MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have been trying to install CUDA Toolkit 11.3, by following the the instructions in the link: [CUDA 11.3 installation on Ubuntu 18.04](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=18.04&target_type=deb_local):

```
$ wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu1804.pin
$ sudo mv cuda-ubuntu1804.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
$ wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.3.1/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-3-local_11.3.1-465.19.01-1_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-3-local_11.3.1-465.19.01-1_amd64.deb
$ sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-3-local/7fa2af80.pub
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

All commands succeeded, the last command failed as follows:

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install cuda
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 cuda : Depends: cuda-11-3 (>= 11.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix this? Do I need to install some dependency? Or another version of CUDA?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077061/how-do-i-install-nvidia-and-cuda-drivers-into-ubuntu/1077063#1077063  Using the .run file seems easier than untangling all the deb dependencies

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on Ubuntu 20.04. At last I took these actions:

- Clean all `cuda*`:

  ```
  sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda*
  sudo apt remove --autoremove nvidia-cuda-toolkit
  sudo apt-get autoremove
  sudo apt-get autoclean
  ```
- Then I used instructions from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads,
  consecutively selecting the options:

  1. *Linux*
  2. *x86_64*
  3. *Ubuntu*
  4. *20.04* (or *18.04* in your case)
  5. The last choice is the *Installer Type*. The same as you, I tried *deb (local)*, and *runfile (local)* and both failed. But with the option *deb (network)* I succeeded at last. You can easily find there set of commands, but may be more successful for you.