# Trying to install CUDA driver, "fatal error: asm/kmap_types.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

I had the CUDA driver installed on my machine (Ubuntu 20.04). It was working ... until it stopped working (not sure what happened). So I'm trying to reinstall it by running:

`sudo sh cuda_11.1.0_455.23.05_linux.run`

where I downloaded `cuda_11.1.0_455.23.05_linux.run` from NVIDIA's website. However, I get an error saying to look at `/var/log/nvidia-installer.log` to learn more about why the installation failed. The file contains a really large error message, I've pasted part of it below. I'm not quite sure what to do

```
In file included from /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-frontend.c:13:
   /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:119:10: fatal error: asm/kmap_types.h: No such file or directory
     119 | #include <asm/kmap_types.h>         /* page table entry lookup          */
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   In file included from /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv.c:14:
   /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:119:10: fatal error: asm/kmap_types.h: No such file or directory
     119 | #include <asm/kmap_types.h>         /* page table entry lookup          */
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:287: /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-frontend.o] Error 1
   In file included from /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-dma.c:15:
   /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:119:10: fatal error: asm/kmap_types.h: No such file or directory
     119 | #include <asm/kmap_types.h>         /* page table entry lookup          */
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-vm.o
   compilation terminated.
   make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:287: /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv.o] Error 1
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-vtophys.o
   In file included from /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-acpi.c:15:
   /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:119:10: fatal error: asm/kmap_types.h: No such file or directory
     119 | #include <asm/kmap_types.h>         /* page table entry lookup          */
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:287: /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-dma.o] Error 1
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/os-interface.o
   In file included from /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-p2p.c:15:
   /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:119:10: fatal error: asm/kmap_types.h: No such file or directory
     119 | #include <asm/kmap_types.h>         /* page table entry lookup          */
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:287: /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-acpi.o] Error 1
   In file included from /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-mmap.c:15:
   /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:119:10: fatal error: asm/kmap_types.h: No such file or directory
     119 | #include <asm/kmap_types.h>         /* page table entry lookup          */
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/os-mlock.o
   make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:287: /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-p2p.o] Error 1
   make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:287: /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-mmap.o] Error 1
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/os-pci.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/os-registry.o
   In file included from /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-pat.c:15:
   /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:119:10: fatal error: asm/kmap_types.h: No such file or directory
     119 | #include <asm/kmap_types.h>         /* page table entry lookup          */
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:287: /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-pat.o] Error 1
   In file included from /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-cray.c:15:
   /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:119:10: fatal error: asm/kmap_types.h: No such file or directory
     119 | #include <asm/kmap_types.h>         /* page table entry lookup          */
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/os-usermap.o
   make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:287: /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-cray.o] Error 1
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-modeset-interface.o
   In file included from /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-usermap.c:15:
   /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:119:10: fatal error: asm/kmap_types.h: No such file or directory
     119 | #include <asm/kmap_types.h>         /* page table entry lookup          */
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:287: /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-usermap.o] Error 1
   In file included from /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-procfs.c:15:
   /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:119:10: fatal error: asm/kmap_types.h: No such file or directory
     119 | #include <asm/kmap_types.h>         /* page table entry lookup          */
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-pci-table.o
   make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:287: /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-procfs.o] Error 1
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-kthread-q.o
   In file included from /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/common/inc/nv-pci.h:15,
                    from /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-pci.c:12:
   /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:119:10: fatal error: asm/kmap_types.h: No such file or directory
     119 | #include <asm/kmap_types.h>         /* page table entry lookup          */
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:287: /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-pci.o] Error 1
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-memdbg.o
   In file included from /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/nvidia/nv-i2c.c:17:
   /tmp/selfgz3864/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.23.05/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:119:10: fatal error: asm/kmap_types.h: No such file or directory
     119 | #include <asm/kmap_types.h>         /* page table entry lookup          */
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Do you have the linux-headers-xxx and linux-headers-xxx-generic packages installed for your kernel?

Comment: @ubfan1 running `sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` seems to suggest so:

Comment: `Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-5.11.0-25-generic is already the newest version (5.11.0-25.27~20.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
`

Comment: Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077061/how-do-i-install-nvidia-and-cuda-drivers-into-ubuntu/1077063#1077063  Clean out all the nvidia* and libnvidia* packages, then install from the standard repos the Nvidia 470 driver(tested). then run the cuda run script, and reject any Nvidia installs. With CUDA separated from the Nvidia video, it wont fall on its face every kernel update.

Comment: @ubfan1 thank you this worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the instructions in the [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077061/how-do-i-install-nvidia-and-cuda-drivers-into-ubuntu/1077063#1077063) suggested by @ubfan1 solved the problem