# I manually removed Nvidia CUDA, that corrupted my Nvidia drivers, and now I cannot reinstall them

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, package-management, ubuntu-drivers, additional-drivers

I manually removed Nvidia CUDA, that corrupted my Nvidia drivers. I removed all Nvidia old drivers and packages, and now I cannot reinstall the drivers no matter what I've tried.

**A. When I try `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-510` I get this:**

```
❯ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-510
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libegl-mesa0:i386 libegl1:i386 libgbm1:i386 libgles2:i386 libnvidia-cfg1-510 libnvidia-common-510 libnvidia-compute-510:i386
  libnvidia-decode-510 libnvidia-decode-510:i386 libnvidia-encode-510 libnvidia-encode-510:i386 libnvidia-extra-510 libnvidia-fbc1-510
  libnvidia-fbc1-510:i386 libnvidia-gl-510 libnvidia-gl-510:i386 libopengl0:i386 libwayland-server0:i386 nvidia-compute-utils-510
  nvidia-dkms-510 nvidia-kernel-common-510 nvidia-kernel-source-510 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-510 screen-resolution-extra
  xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-510
Suggested packages:
  xfonts-100dpi | xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libegl-mesa0:i386 libegl1:i386 libgbm1:i386 libgles2:i386 libnvidia-cfg1-510 libnvidia-common-510 libnvidia-compute-510:i386
  libnvidia-decode-510 libnvidia-decode-510:i386 libnvidia-encode-510 libnvidia-encode-510:i386 libnvidia-extra-510 libnvidia-fbc1-510
  libnvidia-fbc1-510:i386 libnvidia-gl-510 libnvidia-gl-510:i386 libopengl0:i386 libwayland-server0:i386 nvidia-compute-utils-510
  nvidia-dkms-510 nvidia-driver-510 nvidia-kernel-common-510 nvidia-kernel-source-510 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-510
  screen-resolution-extra xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-510
0 upgraded, 29 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 274 MB/274 MB of archives.
After this operation, 677 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 xserver-xorg-core amd64 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 [1,339 kB]
Get:2 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  libnvidia-cfg1-510 510.47.03-0ubuntu1 [79.3 kB]
Err:2 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  libnvidia-cfg1-510 510.47.03-0ubuntu1
  File has unexpected size (79336 != 79334). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 152.199.20.126 443]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA512:8f5a02ed17ee94b6b654813954395e8e706beaeab9d88a20a9b206c743632f8b2322dae0b0e11b71c4a80d6e95777bef161602452cc7a39b31228294e618a952
   - SHA256:a118e3a281e4384e7d893a7ac161030b4349f5a1fb8e868efef1d839f355324e
   - SHA1:1bb2e0897414475b4fc0ca54d165b471f81c7455 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:2a749d8d0c15592650cdef6a2e733724 [weak]
   - Filesize:79334 [weak]
Get:3 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  libnvidia-common-510 510.47.03-0ubuntu1 [10.3 kB]
Err:3 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  libnvidia-common-510 510.47.03-0ubuntu1
  File has unexpected size (10272 != 10268). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 152.199.20.126 443]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA512:f8ca821093ba421b6654f1d03ff00c8e93f09f2e2b1134f0a148754f82b30427e38406bb3065bce5e362096a1ce3955912232176dbb569e5464cdfd3278c0e05
   - SHA256:841bab9655273a43bc2e6a8fc4468b0b9114befda4dc28b0ef551acf9dde8da0
   - SHA1:0cd86d68329c0139dd3b13c00fde910cf2e022ab [weak]
   - MD5Sum:da6b782f5b37d8f9c1d6724b3f752cc1 [weak]
   - Filesize:10268 [weak]

  [OMITTED SOME ERRORS AS THE QUESTION WAS TOO LONG]

https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/./libnvidia-gl-510_510.47.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File has unexpected size (168436082 != 168436078). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 152.199.20.126 443]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:42c3ce053f27af8184f2cde143fd1dfae2757ac79afef943f02f7042a153b70dd01c2d6fff047a69f55d9a28f2dcd8e543c1e696920689cf0a96880001a1892a
    - SHA256:77f37644b2c3c3be8f4b2ce32b09bec2bdf7e4598152b77435eb16b99cf2d86e
    - SHA1:37dec7e0a340d2f0ec7da4544d7ff10d61fe8543 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:1abafdf15eb8ab8473c1e563c3b2589f [weak]
    - Filesize:168436078 [weak]
E: Failed to fetch https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/./libnvidia-gl-510_510.47.03-0ubuntu1_i386.deb  File has unexpected size (22997980 != 22997978). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 152.199.20.126 443]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:c7fa48dd2c2eb2b5a8d30270b4d54073fc1ba88c95d96d0a0199760457b36e03a78d77a2c7fd1a0b12f6b4dfd1bf381d642538f847421f5f530c054692695070
    - SHA256:0a4ab50121d7360017c95d4a4e9834740d97598fbd9a8488c354aef0061be620
    - SHA1:f5e2bff6659fcb064a0353ceee15b1bee40a5d59 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:2bbed1ad658303b5bbcb15c01b65f649 [weak]
    - Filesize:22997978 [weak]
E: Failed to fetch https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/./nvidia-compute-utils-510_510.47.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File has unexpected size (351170 != 351168). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 152.199.20.126 443]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:afc9562289a5e95201fe9648a3a97251cf16b3dc276df63b74985bba425603ce737e364b24266dcb6c9a24f44bf1952212da7703fb4cfc1671143ed9a38fce01
    - SHA256:db64d2daee0b2be91bd8a83c632d168d2ef80ae7bc88252871b5108f58ade484
    - SHA1:27c0a5a1c0132d4352bbd2aaa0c6e3ca2b7130c0 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:03ea0cdbe620df642785af3f7c8b25d8 [weak]
    - Filesize:351168 [weak]
E: Failed to fetch https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/./nvidia-kernel-source-510_510.47.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File has unexpected size (29148108 != 29148106). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 152.199.20.126 443]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:592809d439bd64cd95f0ed4311594f3687020207e013aad1862962bb2d3d1f3ccc5901958e350cb0ff6f4cfa44fb83dec841a3b4a3383e9e3a27472bb6b89d82
    - SHA256:befae4050cd78417d53ee639b80e7c7924488b3dc4f42cb7cdb33c3fbd90a0a9
    - SHA1:b7a46de62836ee000b8d65293e2ea293622e78cd [weak]
    - MD5Sum:df494f99b6148692836483a60bda81ee [weak]
    - Filesize:29148106 [weak]
E: Failed to fetch https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/./nvidia-kernel-common-510_510.47.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File has unexpected size (20475412 != 20475410). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 152.199.20.126 443]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:9db25222c969d48117821dcdb230ce58d9a5bcf3cd45340bfba28effa3ba6d82e77391a2baeade24eb9f168880330884ba6796c5bb47b02c3cc14e9346b32261
    - SHA256:7f1a63c13894b3256448a7fc27a543fe99b30ee0ce530bfb475b72a9d05e8758
    - SHA1:eb544727a3d570395eab05a28f8c4dcc47c32e1c [weak]
    - MD5Sum:c10a8c3dc0ec964a488ae2a6b5a9ddd9 [weak]
    - Filesize:20475410 [weak]
E: Failed to fetch https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/./nvidia-dkms-510_510.47.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File has unexpected size (29506 != 29502). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 152.199.20.126 443]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:04926ad2cf951a9ec67f1cef0386edefa8783f230a9f1c983525c838a60a8b3717212d75dc363dd3b0642cd2d682f36ee68149a236a9fc398985e4a01d8283ff
    - SHA256:d83cd90912323b66fd68492571a59cb40b72164e6c0fcc6edaab85dec4c54488
    - SHA1:ea354fa5f6b150fa0b26eab27503985198fd8663 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:8a7f6f74fc8ed4ed37f09dc67a3dadde [weak]
    - Filesize:29502 [weak]
E: Failed to fetch https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/./nvidia-utils-510_510.47.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File has unexpected size (385746 != 385742). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 152.199.20.126 443]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:8a1ae07ce0bfa9cef48942d6bd01f5e591f1a106e72d61fddd1a58712287caefdc8747c32a9753a749f1fe48e1204f050262cf945f312c6b7b57d4065b747a75
    - SHA256:295367f214acb6730f04069ccc0fad653142c476197d3d98373dcb4da96741ad
    - SHA1:ac68c3074f0656d9dc5d51ccb68bdf1404c33456 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:d9e3a78f46d5672169583131014c0290 [weak]
    - Filesize:385742 [weak]
E: Failed to fetch https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/./xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-510_510.47.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File has unexpected size (1396210 != 1396208). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 152.199.20.126 443]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:c4a40f5df40a72786ef2247e9f6bab3f806cc8e4b56006dec1c47d0246b64042d6a8ac82cbf29c1a946af9fdfb060ed361aec62cfa97357705029acb8a47a757
    - SHA256:e0528992ab9174cd619a0ff7bf1ca520947bb4e4d4549e240396051f4754ba26
    - SHA1:7c9d33b09abf974c4682b0de98431a1d659963a7 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:9425c744e698207d84a1bb81141482ef [weak]
    - Filesize:1396208 [weak]
E: Failed to fetch https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/./nvidia-driver-510_510.47.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File has unexpected size (445970 != 445968). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 152.199.20.126 443]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:638dd734300038da04cfbdd10505d3fc658432c5172c4a9f249feb7c82234001f5aaee396048038d737d295fd99dc36e3e74453f659f228558387e81fc41e5b1
    - SHA256:02c9b45d32b90f4bd7086c1e3be18c1fb03a748cce2d714e3e0d0435dcedea5c
    - SHA1:956d68c8c927bc744ef7a3b6b4f586579ff68fbf [weak]
    - MD5Sum:341da7c25b9eed2ea8c8b5a61fe8bfa9 [weak]
    - Filesize:445968 [weak]
E: Failed to fetch https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/./nvidia-settings_510.47.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  File has unexpected size (899054 != 899052). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 152.199.20.126 443]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:5d465cd5ffd24baa02089be8f9e999b8b85b6aaf738f6394602ef7189dc858099b8242fa2139d7e7925e30891a2ab0c2d74a8986baa612da3b2a94e132ef1450
    - SHA256:0f1acee3c8670578b207fb032dfd72f0ffbeb9217162c3161aca47ddb3c6bb1e
    - SHA1:5e02e4b1acc30b3c994b8dae70e794ac74d141fc [weak]
    - MD5Sum:1ced143ba53c79a905ac9682519431bd [weak]
    - Filesize:899052 [weak]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

**B. I download the .run file from Nvidia's website and when trying to install I get:

```
An alternate method of installing the NVIDIA driver was detected. (This is   
  usually a package provided by your distributor.) A driver installed via that 
  method may integrate better with your system than a driver installed by      
  nvidia-installer.

  Please review the message provided by the maintainer of this alternate       
  installation method and decide how to proceed:
```

And then:

```
ERROR: The Nouveau kernel driver is currently in use by your system.  This   
         driver is incompatible with the NVIDIA driver, and must be disabled   
         before proceeding.  Please consult the NVIDIA driver README and your  
         Linux distribution's documentation for details on how to correctly    
         disable the Nouveau kernel driver.
```

And lastly:

```
 
  WARNING: One or more modprobe configuration files to disable Nouveau are     
           already present at:
           /usr/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf,          
           /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf.  Please be   
           sure you have rebooted your system since these files were written.  
           If you have rebooted, then Nouveau may be enabled for other         
           reasons, such as being included in the system initial ramdisk or in 
           your X configuration file.  Please consult the NVIDIA driver README 
           and your Linux distribution's documentation for details on how to   
           correctly disable the Nouveau kernel driver.
```

**C. When I'm trying to select the drivers from Software & Updates, I get this:**

[My Software & Updates list additional drivers list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fH9a.png)

[The error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMpq2.png)

What can I do to remove any residues and succesfully reinstall the Nvidia drivers?

Comment: Removing Cuda does not remove the Nvidia repository.

Comment: can you not check off the nvidia driver in the additional drivers list, and save?

Comment: No, I cannot check off the driver, it gives the error in the photo I shared. I might have removed the Nvidia repository by mistake, I tried re-adding it with sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa but I get errors in this format "W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:3
"

Comment: The standard repositorie (restricted) for 20.04 have everything you need for the Nvidia 510 driver -- no need for Nvidia or graphics-drivers repos.  Remove those repos, update, then clean out every \*nvidia\* package. Then you may install the 510 Nvidia driver. Use the .run CUDA install and avoid any Nvidia driver offer. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077061/how-do-i-install-nvidia-and-cuda-drivers-into-ubuntu/1077063#1077063

Comment: First, run `sudo apt update` to update your package list. Next, if you still get the same error after that, wait an hour or so and try again. You DO NOT want to install the nvidia driver from the run file. You will end up with a broken driver every time there is a kernel update.

Comment: Ideally, you would normally install the proprietary driver by using `sudo apt update` and `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` Have you tried this?