# I reinstalled the Nvidia proprietary drivers and USB stopped working after reboot. Neither my mouse nor my kb work and I am stuck in the login screen

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, usb, additional-drivers

After encountering a problem with my Nvidia drivers (described here: [enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410347/i-manually-removed-nvidia-cuda-that-corrupted-my-nvidia-drivers-and-now-i-cann) ), I managed to reinstall them using the instructions here: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/updating-the-cuda-linux-gpg-repository-key/

After rebooting, USB stopped working at all. Neither my mouse nor my keyboard work and I am stuck in the login screen. When the computer powers up, the lights of the keyboard lightup, but while booting to Ubuntu, they all go off. I think the USB ports don't even get power.

When I enter recovery mode, if I run lsusb in command line, I can see the buses and the connected devices listed properly, so I guess the problem has something to do with the Nvidia drivers, as the problems occurs when entering the Ubuntu GUI in the login screen.

In my Windows 11 partition, USB works fine as well.

How can I could I attempt to solve this problem?

Comment: Again: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410347/i-manually-removed-nvidia-cuda-that-corrupted-my-nvidia-drivers-and-now-i-cann#comment2450842_1410347

Comment: This is a different problem. I managed to reinstall the Nvidia drivers, but when I rebooted, I couldn't get past the login screen, as USB had stopped working and I couldn't use my mouse or my keyboard.

Comment: No, not different. It's a direct consequence of you doing the opposite of what has been - correctly - suggested.

Comment: maybe try the answers you've already gotten instead of arguing that you know better, and then encountering errors. You clearly *don't* know better, or else you wouldn't have these errors.

Comment: I proceeded on my own before I got any answers. Now I cannot login to my system to do what has been suggested

Comment: It seems to me that the only viable option is to remove the nvidia proprietary drivers and use any one of those that comes *with ubuntu*. (Win key start typing: Software & Updates> Click on it, then go to Additional Drivers > ... [I see 6 versions here, in 20.04] )

Comment: I  followed the instructions up to a point, deleted all nvidia packages and reinstalled nouveau (as otherwise the system wouldn't even get to login screen), and now I am again stuck in the login screen as USB doesn't work and I can't use mouse or keyboard. How do I proceed?

Comment: When I enter recovery mode and run lsusb all my devices are listed properly, but when I boot normally and get to the login screen USB doesn't work.