# Wrongful error on version mismatch - gcc 11.4.0 kernel nvidia-cuda-515

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, gcc, cuda

There was an update in my Ubuntu 22.04.03 LTS OS last week, and my nvidia-515 with cuda 11.7 broke. On reinstalling, it fails. I'm stuck, tried to debug and inspect logs - which points to version mismatch, but the versions are indeed the same **11.4.0**.

Is it the name that needs some change. Forcing alias of cc and gcc to x86_64 also hasn't change anything. Tried multiple iterations with reboots after each attempt, to no avail. Sadly using "apt install nvidia-driver-515" is not an option because it install 525 due to its transition. Have a hard need for driver-515 with cuda 11.7.

```
$ sudo ./cuda_11.7.0_515.43.04_linux.run
[Error - listed in nvidia-installer.log below]

$ vim /var/log/nvidia-installer.log
...
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
  You are using:           cc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0

$ ll /usr/bin/gcc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Aug 20 09:53 /usr/bin/gcc -> /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11*

$ ll /usr/bin/cc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Aug 20 09:16 /usr/bin/cc -> /etc/alternatives/cc*

$ ll /etc/alternatives/cc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Aug 20 09:16 /etc/alternatives/cc -> /usr/bin/gcc*

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0

$ x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11 --version
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Comment: Which kernel are you using? What video card?  5.15 is the only valid Ubuntu 22.04 kernel that takes gcc-11.  The 6.5 kernel takes gcc-12 to build the Nvidia 535/545 module, but just having gcc-12 installed is enough, no need to mess with /bin/gcc links.  Your video card may have max Nvidia drivers/CUDA versions, but CUDA installs I've made since 8 don't care about the Nvidia driver. My CUDA11.8 samples still run fine with the Nvidia 545 driver.

Answer (score 0):

My cuda install recently broke after a system update, too. I'm on 22.04 had a hard need for **nvidia-driver-535** and cuda toolkit **12.1**. Perhaps this will work for you with driver-515 and 11.4.

I was getting the same compiler mismatch errors you saw, so I manually updated the symlink in `/usr/bin/gcc` from **gcc-11** to **gcc-12**.

I removed and purged all nvidia drivers with

`sudo apt remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'`

and restarted to confirm there were no nvidia drivers in place.

Then I followed the instructions here:

[How do I install NVIDIA and CUDA drivers into Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077061/how-do-i-install-nvidia-and-cuda-drivers-into-ubuntu/1288405#1288405)

essentially:

- `apt install nvidia-driver-535`
- restart to confirm driver-535 was in place
- ran the local runfile ignoring the runfile installer's warning and de-selecting the driver:
- `sudo ./cuda_12.1.1_530.30.02_linux.run`

Currently, `nvidia-smi`, `nvcc --version`, and all the cuda-samples are Working as Designed. I hope this helps you, too.

Comment: I'm not certain the compiler updates from gcc-11 to gcc-12 were required for this fix. I am certain I'd prefer to handle this through update-alternatives vs manually re-creating the symlink.