# Installing CUDA 12.0 on Ubuntu 22.04 and Driver Version: 535.86.05

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, cuda

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- GPU: RTX3090
- Nvidia driver: 535.86.05

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.86.05              Driver Version: 535.86.05    CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

I have followed the [instructions](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-12-0-0-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=22.04&target_type=deb_local) to install CUDA 12.0, but it always fails at the end with the following error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing: 
nvidia-dkms-525
cuda-drivers-525
nvidia-driver-525
cuda-drivers
cuda-runtime-12-0
cuda-12-0
cuda-demo-suite-12-0
cuda
```

I reinstall Ubuntu everytime to avoid compatibility issues. I believe that the problem has to do with the driver, because the instructions linked requires nvidia-driver-525, while my driver is `535.86.05`. What is the best option to install CUDA 12.0 with my current setup? Thank you

Comment: I think you are missing a vital point here during the CUDA install.  It should be asking for what you want installed.  If you see my answers at https://askubuntu.com/a/1288405/231142 during the install it tries to install its own NVIDIA driver which will conflict with the versions you have installed already.  But, I haven't tried that install that you are running through as I have only used the `.run` file installs and not the `.deb` ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing with the .run file instead of the .deb, since it asks if you want the driver to be installed too (you don't want that since it will install a different driver version than you already have). At least this method worked for me, also on 22.04 with 535.