# The repository 'cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.4.1.50 Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates, repository

I have this problem when I try to update (`sudo agt-get update`), the full logs after finishing update with the error are:

```
E: The repository 'file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.4.1.50  Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

E: The repository 'file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.6.0.163  Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

E: The repository 'file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2204-8.6.0.163  Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

my system:

**Ubuntu: 20.04.
arch=x86_64.
codename=focal**

I couldn't found anything related with this problem can anyone help me with this?

I include photo for the full logs:
[image: my Full logs image]

Comment: You've corrupted sources with `file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.4.1.50` which needs to be removed.

Comment: You might want to see this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1288405/231142 since the libcudnn does not come from the 2004 repo and they actually do not have a 2204 repo even available.  The 1804 should supply the installation that you need and still install.

Comment: @Terrance but I have NVIDIA Driver Version: 525.125.06,  CUDA Version: 12.0 I am not sure if the 495 version compatible. I have RTX 3080 notebook, do you recommend any other NVIDIA driver version.

Comment: sorry cuda version 11.7

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jun__8_16:49:14_PDT_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.7, V11.7.99
Build cuda_11.7.r11.7/compiler.31442593_0

Comment: I haven't done a new answer for 22.04 yet, but that isn't what I was talking about.  The video driver is insignificant here.  I am only talking about the `libcudnn`.  If you want to try those installs you can always substitute the driver versions for what you want.  The newest NVIDIA driver is `535.86.05` from the repos.  You are more than welcome to use that answer but make sure that you change the version numbers to match what you are installing.

Comment: @Terrance Ok, thank you